# Multiple .col classes not working in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm just trying out Bootstrap and am a bit confused why when I apply multiple .col classes to a div it seems to have no impact. Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="cheryl-winn-boujnida-65955.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Fast photo printing
        </h4>
        <p class="card-text">Upload content and have it sent to your address within 3 hours</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="neonbrand-371471.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Total access
        </h4>
        <p class="card-text">Access your media from any device, from any location</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="allef-vinicius-205147.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <i class="fa fa-ravelry" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Freedom
        </h4>
        <p class="card-text">Choose your package to suit your needs and usage</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The divs line up ok horizontally on large screens but when I reduce the screen size, the divs stack but don't seem to take into account the settings I am trying to apply with the .col classes.

Answer (score 0):

The columns will stack up if the sum of the column classes value is greater than 12 in Bootstrap. For example, in your code you have given the three div's a class ".col-md-8". So that makes the size of a row 8*3 = 24 which is greater than 12 which cannot be fit in a Bootstrap container. Hence they are getting stacked.

What you should do this to avoid stacking is to set ".col-md-8" to ".col-md-4" and similarly change ".col-sm-10" to ".col-sm-4". This should avoid the stacking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I do want them to stack. They should stack straight away from .col-md but I want them to take up more columns at this size. So at the largest screen size they should take 4 columns each and display horizontally but then when the screen is reduced they should stack but take up most of the columns i.e. most of the width of the screen

Comment: All you have to do then is change  <div class="card" style="width: 20 rem;"> to <div class="card" style="width: auto;"> for all the three cards.